# Troubleshooting Asynchronous Database Connection in Console App Using async/await

Tags: c#

I am trying to run this console app asynchronously but not sure why the program breaks without exception when it tries to connect to the database. I used `dapper` as ORM. I also tried to remove the return type `Task` in the console app but still same issue. How should I troubleshoot further?

This is the console program.

```
public class ConsoleApp : IConsoleApp
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ConsoleApp(IMyService myService, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async void Run(string[] args)
    {                     
        try
        {
            // code removed for brevity.
            
            while (true)
            {                
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option:");                    
                Console.WriteLine("1. Full update");
                
                Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");

                var choice = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (choice)
                {                        
                    case "1":
                        await _myService.FullUpdateAsync(objectIds);
                        break;                        
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid choice. Please try again.");
                        break;
                }                     
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
        
    }
}



public async Task FullUpdateAsync(List<int> objectIds)
    {            
        try
        {
            foreach (var objectId in objectIds)
            {
                using (var connSource = new SqlConnection(_connstringSource))             
                {
                    await connSource.OpenAsync(); // it breaks here and the exception could not be caught.
                    
                    // code removed for brevity
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

If I remove the async and await at the Console app, there is no issue but it prints out below before the process is complete.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option:");                    
Console.WriteLine("1. Full update");

Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");
```

Added more code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        //host.Run();

        // Resolve IConsoleApp and run it. Note: Use interface
        using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var consoleApp = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConsoleApp>();
        consoleApp.Run(args);
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {                    
                services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
                services.AddScoped<IConsoleApp, ConsoleApp>();
            });
}
```

Comment: `async void` is bad

Comment: Make `Run` an `async Task` and use a connection pool, then try again.

Comment: A few more things to improve debugability: use a logging framework instead of console writeline. And maybe span the whole run method in a try/catch.

Comment: Is that IConsoleApp a Dapper thing or where is it from?

Comment: `IConsoleApp` is not a dapper thing. Usually console app access to the api layer and api layer access to the service layer. But, here I am trying to have console app directly accessing to the service layer through DI. @Fildor

Comment: OK. Just making sure you have control over it. Did you go and step it through in the debugger at one point?

Comment: @Fildor ok, i will try using Dapper with Connection Factory

Comment: You must use `await consoleApp.RunAsync(args);`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov you found it. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 3):

You have put `async void Run` which is bad, as you loose exception information.

So your code breaks inside that method (most probably on database connection) and that's why it seems like your app does not work without no reason.

So, to verify that, first put `async Task Run` and then await that method appropriately.

Additionally, you can enable the debugger to break on all C# exceptions in Exception Settings:
[image]

Then try to debug the code with step over/step into:
[image]

Comment: Still would expect some error in the console (if console is enabled)

Comment: I have enabled this option with `async Task` but the exception could not be caught.

Comment: @Steve and what happens if you debug through the code with "step over"  button?

Comment: @Steve: are there any other `async void`s in your app at all? Is the code that calls `IConsoleApp.Run` awaiting the result?

Comment: no, now i changed back to my original code to return void and it works. But still it will print `Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option:");                    
Console.WriteLine("1. Full update");

Console.Write("Enter your choice: ");` when the process is not completed.

Answer (score 0):

My immediate suspicion would be that you have `new SqlConnection(_connstringSource)` *inside* the loop. So, if you running synchronously, it is probably opening and closing. Inefficient, but not breaking. In `async` mode, it creates connections and eventually runs out of them.

Put this line outside the loop and see if it fixes the problem